# What's a reason for this function to exist?

Tags: go, indirection

In [encoding/json](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go) the un-exported reflectValue function passes on all its arguments to another function.

```
func(e *encodeState) reflectValue(v reflect.Value, opts encOpts)       
{           
    valueEncoder(v)(e, v, opts)
}
```

The call to valueEncoder can be made from wherever reflectValue is called. What's the motivation for this additional function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method can be replaced by direct calls to `valueEncoder(v)(e, v, opts)`. The method is not needed to satisfy an interface, nor is it accessed through reflection.

The method was [much longer back in 2011](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2afc46f2b213336ca4ac1d518b9e9d4f6b5b0fbc/src/pkg/json/encode.go#L223). The current method may be there because of the past history. It's also possible that the author thought that code readability is improved by encapsulating `valueEncoder(v)(e, v, opts)` in a method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the motivation of the author of this code. But I suppose that e.reflectValue() is a helper function which makes this code more precies and readable.

When I look at the definition of this fucntion:

```
func (e *encodeState) reflectValue(v reflect.Value, opts encOpts)
```

It's pretty clear to me that reflectValue somehow changes encodeState based on reflect value and some encoding options.

When I look at this defintion:

```
func valueEncoder(v reflect.Value) encoderFunc
```

I have no idea about what's going on, all I see is a higher-order function.

Function calls are expensive in golang, but encoding/json package is not expected to be very fast.